# PHP key() returning the key for the next item in the array, not the current one

Tags: php

The code here is pretty simple, so I'm not sure what could be happening. [This site](http://dev.dannymcgee.net/wargame/) that I made a couple of years ago has been working fine the whole time, and today I randomly checked on it to find it completely borked. I'm not sure if it was a PHP upgrade performed by my webhost or maybe an automatic WordPress update that broke it, but in any case, the code is not behaving as expected.

In the WordPress loop, for each post, this code is running:

```
$stats = array(
    'recon' => 'Recon',
    'inf' => 'Infantry',
    'fist' => 'Fire Support',
    'atgm' => 'ATGM',
    'armor' => 'Armor',
    'arty' => 'Artillery',
    'aa' => 'Anti-Air',
    'air' => 'Aircraft',
    'heli' => 'Helicopters'
);

foreach( $stats as $stat_name ):
    $stat_key = key( $stats );

    // DEBUG:
    echo '<p>' . $stat_key . ' : ' . $stat_name . '</p>';

    ...
    next( $stats );
endforeach;
```

As you can see on the [live site](http://dev.dannymcgee.net/wargame/), `key( $stats )` is returning the key for the *next* item in the array and not the current one, and returning null for the last item in the array. What could possibly be going wrong here?

Comment: Works [**perfectly fine**](https://3v4l.org/p2TIY) for me.

Comment: @ObsidianAge The output for 5.6 is messed up I believe.

Comment: Obsidian, it looks like you're getting the same result as I am for PHP 5.6.30. I guess I must have gotten *downgraded* somehow (which is bizarre), but in any case, is that really the expected functionality for 5.6? How would I do what I'm actually trying to accomplish here in 5.6?

Comment: @dannymcgee I think you just need a `foreach($stats as $key => $stat_name)`  no need of calling the functions key() and next()

Comment: your using foreach total wrong, thats what

Comment: Thanks @codisfy -- I'm a front-end developer so PHP isn't really my thing. That did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make use of the key option in the foreach

```
 foreach( $stats as $key => $stat_name ):

   // DEBUG:
   echo '<p>' . $stat_key . ' : ' . $stat_name . '</p>';

endforeach;
```

I wouldn't suggest calling, next while in a foreach loop, it will do the iteration for you.  Likely it's already done so when you call key, because its moved the pointer on to the next item already.

Foreach can do weird things when you mess with the structure of the array because it creates a shadow copy of the array (I forget the exact way its explained, and they may have changed it somewhat in 7).  In any case,  I'm not sure what affect calling next will have, maybe none, because of the way that it handles iterating with foreach.  I never tried it!

If you want to use next, then use the `do` or `while` loop.

The really proper syntax would be

```
foreach( $stats as $key => $stat_name ){
   // DEBUG:
   echo '<p>' . $stat_key . ' : ' . $stat_name . '</p>';
}
```

The Alternative syntax is useful if you have it in html, such as

```
<?php foreach( $stats as $key => $stat_name ): ?>
     <p><?=$stat_key;?> : <?=$stat_name;?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<div> ....
```

This is because the `endforeach;` is more descriptive then the `}` and it can be very easy to lose track of the `}` when mixed with HTML and other control structures (like if statements).  With the alternative statement you wind up with things like `endforeach;`  `endif;`  instead of `} }` .  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @ArtisticPhoenix, I'm a front-end dev so PHP isn't really my thing. That syntax definitely makes a lot more sense, and I don't know how I didn't figure that out when I was first putting this together.

Comment: its also not really proper to use the alternative syntax the  `: ... endforeach;`  typically I only use that if I put PHP in HTML and then it only help to keep track of the end tags, you can simply use `foreach(....){ ...stuff ... }` curry brackets.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to use the endif / endforeach syntax because it's always mixed in with a bunch of HTML markup (there's a lot of HTML in the ellipsis up there) so the curly braces tend to get lost. I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: I use template systems, ( mainly one I built ) and almost never mix HTML with PHP these days.  I wrote it about 5 years ago while on vacation for my work, lol.   We still use it, it's much like twig but a bit simpler.  But that makes sense, It's not wrong to use it just more verbose.